# Angular, call service function from current service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service called "sharedData" with some functions, how to call one of these functions from another such functions? here the code(marked trouble functions with "???????"): Thanks

```
service('sharedData', function ($http) {
    var refillList = [];
    var orderCart = {
        orderPlace: null,
        orderList: [],
        totalSum: 0
    };

    return {
        ....
        addRefill: function(value) {
           ...here some logic....
        },

        addOrder: function(order) {
            ...here some logic....
        },
        sendOrder: function(order, refill) {
            $http.get(config.urls.ajaxOrder + "{\"order\":{\"table_id\":" + orderCart.orderPlace + ",\"item_id\":" + order.id + ",\"amount\":1,\"action\":1}}").success(function(dataDetails) {
                if (dataDetails.success) {
                    if (refill == 1) {
                        // Filling refill list
                        ??????????????????this.addRefill(order);?????????
                    }
                    // Filling order cart
                    ?????????this.addOrder(order);?????????????
                }
            });
        }
    };
}).
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should save reference to `this`.

`var self = this;` is a common practice.

```
sendOrder: function(order, refill) {
    var self = this;
    $http.get(config.urls.ajaxOrder + "{\"order\":{\"table_id\":" + orderCart.orderPlace + ",\"item_id\":" + order.id + ",\"amount\":1,\"action\":1}}")
        .success(function(dataDetails) {
            if (dataDetails.success) {
                if (refill == 1) {
                    // Filling refill list
                    self.addRefill(order);
                }
                    // Filling order cart
                    self.addOrder(order);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

### Update 2016

Now, with ES6 you can use arrow functions like this:

```
sendOrder: function(order, refill) {
    $http.get(config.urls.ajaxOrder + "{\"order\":{\"table_id\":" + orderCart.orderPlace + ",\"item_id\":" + order.id + ",\"amount\":1,\"action\":1}}")
        .success(dataDetails => {
            if (dataDetails.success) {
                if (refill == 1) {
                    // Filling refill list
                    this.addRefill(order);
                }
                    // Filling order cart
                    this.addOrder(order);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Arrow functions doesn't change a context, so `this` will be the same `this`.

[MDN article about arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this in this callback function refers to the parent container of the callback which is $http in this case. What you'll want to do is create an instance of the parent object outside of the callback and reference that from within the callback.

Something like:

```
....
{
    ....
    addRefill: function(value) {
       ...here some logic....
    },

    addOrder: function(order) {
        ...here some logic....
    },
    sendOrder: function(order, refill) {
        var rootObj = this;
        $http.get(config.urls.ajaxOrder + "{\"order\":{\"table_id\":" + orderCart.orderPlace + ",\"item_id\":" + order.id + ",\"amount\":1,\"action\":1}}").success(function(dataDetails) {
            if (dataDetails.success) {
                if (refill == 1) {
                    // Filling refill list
                    rootObj.addRefill(order);
                }
                // Filling order cart
                rootObj.addOrder(order);
            }
        });
    }
};
....
```

This is of course just a solution but the main concept to keep in mind is that the function is being called from the success promise not from your object.