# A Javascript function which creates an object which calls the function itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an angular service that returns a new object.

That's fine and good and works. `new MakeRoll()` creates an instance.  But `self.add`, near the end also calls `new MakeRoll()` and that doesn't create an instance when I call add like I think it should.

I'm probably doing this all wrong but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
var services = angular.module('services', []);

services.factory('Roll', [function() {
  var MakeRoll = function () {
    var self = {};
    self.rolls = [];
    self.add = function(number, sizeOfDice, add) {
      var newRoll = {};
      newRoll.number = number || 1;
      newRoll.sizeOfDice = sizeOfDice || 6;
      newRoll.add = add || 0;
      newRoll.rollDice = function() {
        var result = 0;
        var results=[];
        for (var i = 0; i < newRoll.number; i++) {
          var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * newRoll.sizeOfDice) + 1; 
          result += roll;
          results.push(roll);
        }
        newRoll.results = results;
        newRoll.result = result;
        newRoll.Roll = new MakeRoll();
      };
      self.rolls.push(newRoll);
      return self;
    };
    self.remove = function(index) {
      self.rolls.splice(index, 1);
    };
    self.get = function(index) {
      return self.rolls[index];
    };
    return self;
  };
  return new MakeRoll();
}
]);
```

Comment: You'd have to ask the service for the new MakeRoll instance in this case since your context will be the place where you are executing the .add() method, not the service. You might refactor your service to a pattern more like this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16838581/1861459

Comment: I don't believe I can ask the service for a new MakeRoll instance, since it always gives me a singleton.  Nor am I sure how to make a service with a dependency on itself.

Answer (score 0):

angular service is designed to be singleton to accomplish some business logic, so don't mix up plain model with angular service. if you want to have more objects, just create a constructor and link it in service to be operated on.

```
function MakeRoll() {
...
}

angular.module('service', []).factory('Roll', function () {
    var rolls = [];

    return {
        add: add,
        remove: remove,
        get: get
    }

    function add() {
        // var o = new MakrRoll();
        // rolls.push(o);
    }

    function remove(o) {
        // remove o from rolls
    }

    function get(o) {
        // get o from rolls
    }
});
```